# ColdFusion DSN with DB2 via ODBC

Tags: coldfusion, odbc, db2

I'm attempting to connect a ColdFusion application to a DB2 ODBC DSN.

Here's my error message:

```
Connection verification failed for data source: <DSN NAME>
java.sql.SQLException: [Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30082N Attempt to establish connection failed with security reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID"). SQLSTATE=08001 
The root cause was that: java.sql.SQLException: [Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30082N Attempt to establish connection failed with security reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID"). SQLSTATE=08001
```

I've installed DB2 client tools on the server ColdFusion runs on. I've verified the credentials are correct.

Comment: What is your connection string?

Comment: Connection string, no clue.  I just hit cf administrator, enter the name onetest as the dsn, choose ODBC Socket connection.  next page, I tell it to hook up with the system DSN you enter in the windows odbc section called <DSN NAME>. I give it the user name and password and hit enter.

Comment: I have not used ColdFusion, so I am probably of no use.  But it seems that it is possible to provide one.  http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/5.0/Advanced_ColdFusion_Administration/datasources_ADV_MJS4.htm

Comment: Re Mark: In most cases, Coldfusion manages the connection strings for you. You enter the database details in an admin form and it builds the string. That's a great feature most of the time,...unless you have a configuration that's not well documented.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a DB2 guy, but have you seen the Coldfusion DB2 Universal Driver doc located here?
http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=datasources_ADV_MJS_07.html

Based on your comments, you're using ODBC Socket instead. So while this isn't 1 to 1 what you're asking, it might have something useful: Configure Solaris to DB2 ODBC
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/171/tn_17188.html

The other thing to keep in mind is that DB2 is only supported in CF Enterprise and Developer Editions. http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/systemreqs/

Answer (score 0):

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/801/80121c8.html

This CFMX doc ended up being what we went with to get it working.

Thanks to SO for pointing us in the right direction.